# How TextBox accepts positive and negative decimal values in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

In my projcet(WPF) textbox allow only positive and negative decimal numbers .I used Regular expression then it accepts -.values.but it is taking the values like this

-123.-2 it is not correct.my requirement is it accepts like this

233334
-233333
-2.3444

I used this code.

```
    private void NumericOnly(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = IsTextNumeric(e.Text);

    }


    private static bool IsTextNumeric(string str)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^0-9.-]");
        return reg.IsMatch(str);

    }
```

Somebody please help me.How that text box accepts positive and negative decimal numeric values.

Comment: You could just bind the `TextBox` to a `Double` an let the binding validate the input

Answer (score 0):

You want the negative sign only as the first optional character. So:

```
"-?[\.0-9]+"
```

If you really want to use RegEx for this.
But maybe somethng like [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) would be better?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be to bind to a double as this will highlight the textbox on input error, this is handy to give the user feedback on what they have entered.

Or you could use double.TryParse to check if the number is valid

```
private static bool IsTextNumeric(string str)
{
    double value;
    return double.TryParse(str, out value);
}
```